# Nodejs winston loggin to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to make advanced logging for my project.

```
var winston = require('winston');
var MongoDB = require('winston-mongodb').MongoDB;
var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
    transports : [
        new(winston.transports.MongoDB)({
            db : 'logs'
        })
    ]
});
module.exports = logger;
```

And I got an error:

```
/opt/City13/node_modules/winston-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:16
throw Error("URL must be in the format mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbnam
      ^
Error: URL must be in the format mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbname
at Error (<anonymous>)
at module.exports (/opt/City13/node_modules/winston-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:16:11)
at Function.MongoClient.connect (/opt/City13/node_modules/winston-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:95:16)
at new exports.MongoDB (/opt/City13/node_modules/winston-mongodb/lib/winston-mongodb.js:124:25)
at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/City13/logger/index.js:5:7)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I tried to add host ip adress to settings, but it was not working.

Answer (score 6):

this configuration worked for me:

```
    var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.MongoDB)({
            db : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Book-catalog',
            collection: 'logs'
        })
       ]
    });
```

('Book-catalog' is the name of my database)

Answer (score 4):

From their docs: `db: MongoDB connection uri or preconnected db object.`

You gave it a string 'logs' instead. What it wants is the entire mongodb url needed to connect.

They give you an example in the error message: `mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbname`

If you want to specify the collection (presumably what you're trying to do with 'logs') there's another option called 'collection'